# Problem reading property of a json object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am consuming a body response from a request made from an API and i get my body looking as shown below when i use console.log function

```js
var a= {
    "providers": [{
            "_id": "5cda8a7234157a00265258f2",
            "updatedAt": "2019-05-30T12:53:18.076Z",
            "createdAt": "2019-05-14T09:29:23.663Z",
            "name": "BROOD"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5cda8a723415f200265258f2",
            "updatedAt": "2019-05-30T12:53:18.076Z",
            "createdAt": "2019-05-14T09:29:23.663Z",
            "name": "REDUX"
        }
    ]
}
console.log(a['providers'][0].name)
```

when i try to get the name of the first object in the array for example

```
console.log(body['providers'][0].name)
```

i end up getting an error as shown below

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

i want some help on where am wrong and the right way to access the value in the array

Comment: Its working fine

Comment: This is probably returned asynchronously and you're trying to access it outside the callback

Comment: @adiga am using the request module for nodejs and am displaying it in the function

Comment: Your code works fine. Could you please try to load your page in "private navigation mode" (no cache)) to see if it helps ?

Comment: Also you are talking about your body looking as shown. Do you mean the body of your response ? If so, you have to evaluate your response for your a variable to exist. The html in the response you receive is not evaluated, it is just a string.

Comment: @kamui when using request module in nodejs. the syntax is require(options, function (err,res,body){})  and so i am using the body from the parameter

Comment: The `body` parameter is probably just a string. Its content has probably not been evaluated at the time you try to log the value of `a`. I don't know how nodejs works, but the `body` variable is probably just a string. In the `function(err, res, body){}`, you should try to do something like `$('#somediv').html('<script>' + body + '</script>')` or `eval(body)`
And if you want to use it as a json object, maybe you have to parse it with `var a = JSON.parse(body)` or something like that. (better approach than `eval`)

Answer (score 0):

Code is ok, propably you re trying to access data from api before it`s consumed. Use await for your call.

If you use Chrome, try console.log(your-response);, to see whats is returning, you may see such a small "i" in the console that indicates that the api data was loaded during and after the console.log function.

Answer (score 0):

Try write it with condition when you will need this parameter
Like

```
if(a && a.providers && a.providers.length > 0){
   console.log(a['providers'][0].name)
}
```

Comment: here i get TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Actually that's mean that there is no data from your request for that time

Comment: when i just make a console.log(body) it displays the whole json object but when getting an individual item it shows errors

Comment: Can you show me more code for better understanding?
Also you can add else condition for mine and check value of **a**

Comment: i only used a request module in nodejs to make the request and thats how i tried to check it out

Comment: If _console.log(body)_ shows you whole right json object, then try to call _console.log(body.providers)_ and so on

Comment: Does it show you the whole json object or a string looking like the whole json object ?